# Refactoring a nested bind to use a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, refactoring, bind

I'm having a difficult time trying to refactor some legacy code that uses a nested bind.

The examples show simple instances but don't help when the bind is nested with the inner bind having a placeholder.

Any tips would be appreciated.

We're using C++11.

```
return std::any_of(_vector.begin(), _vector.end(), std::bind(&Foo, std::bind(&Bar, std::placeholders::_1)));
```

Could this be done with two nested lambda's or can it be done with one?

Comment: `[](const T& val) { return Foo(Bar(val)); }`

Comment: @paddy That's the answer.

Comment: Can you still combine that in the std::any_of as an inline?  Seems to have a problem with the braces.

Comment: `std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const T&) { ... })` seems just fine to me.

Comment: It is complaining about the braces... :/

Comment: I dont know what the point of lambdas in C++ are. I get why they're used in haskell (and I used them there too) but in C++.. just why..?

Comment: @JeJo I've been through that and other tutorials, problem is, I'm working with nested binds and one has a ternary function in it, and the data types are a little more complex.  Its just really easy to get confused.  Obv cant post direct code here either so that doesnt help.

Comment: I meant ternary operator.  I managed to get it working by simplifying it, found a way around the code to remove one bind and got rid of the ternary, not it works fine.  The issue was that it was too complicated for a lambda beginner like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `bind` can be simple changed to lambda. All you need to remember that both bind returns "function object" and lambda generates "function object", so you just need to construct equivalent "function object" in terms of prototype and functionality.
I.e. for simple `bind` it goes something like that:

```
x = std::bind(&foo, arg1, arg2, ..., argX);
```

lambda is

```
x = [](T1 val1, T2 val2, ..., Ty valY) {return foo(arg1, arg2, ..., argx);}
```

where each placeholder should be replaced with corresponding `valY`.

All inner binds can be viewed as function calls.

I.e. your case should be like this:

```
return std::any_of(_vector.begin(), _vector.end(), [](T1& val1) {return Foo(Bar(val1);});
```

If you compiler complains about braces make sure you compile for C++11, e.g. have `--std=C++11` for GCC.